# .net + Sharing session over multiple servers with redissessionstateprovider + sessionstate custom mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

I want to use a session created in one server from a another server. Which means i need to share session between two asp.net applications hosted in 2 different servers using Session State Custom mode by RedisSessionStateProvider.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the Redis session state provider, but, by default, ASP.Net uses a cookie to persist te sessionid to the browser. This cookie has the user session id encrypted, using the "MachineKey" entry in Machine.config to get the encryption key.

[See Microsoft Docs for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100)).

If the key is specified in web.config file, it should override the machine key just for your application. You should set the same machinekey entry in both web configs of the two servers.